# How to include symbol of the end of the line ("\n") in regexp

Tags: java, regex

i have regular expression which need to cover multi lines(delete comments from pascal file)

```
\(\*.*?\*\)|\{.*?\}|\/\/(.*$)
```

this works almost fine but

```
\(\*.*?\*\)
```

and

```
\{.*?\}
```

are supposed to work for multilines, but work for single only. How to make them working right(and dont make

> //(.*$)

work for multi lines)

Thanks in advance

Comment: tryed  '/s' at the end of regexp but it doens work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag. Pass it to `Pattern.compile` like so:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("regex", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

You can also set it in the regex with `(?s)`, like: `"(?s)regex"`

Answer (score 1):

This will match literally everything, including newlines:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[\\s\\S]*");
```